# WordPress does not load plugins' libraries properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom made theme working fine since long. Today when I was working on it I found some strange behavior. I think it is due to jquery proper loading. Yet I am not able to solve it.

Here is the link http://lesclefsdorgb.org/aboutus/ 
This page is loading two plugins 
1. Revolution Slider and
2. Floating Menu

On a Chrome consol it gives following error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjZN8.png)

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you including jquery file in function.php or <head> tag

Comment: in <head> tag. Also tried in the footer. Nothing is working.

Comment: May be you are using in a wrong.Go by debugging.